# each page size syncfusion document editor react

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion

How to customize each page size in react syncfusion document editor

```
import * as React from 'react';

import './App.css';

import { DocumentEditorContainerComponent, Toolbar } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-documenteditor';

DocumentEditorContainerComponent.Inject(Toolbar);

function App() {

  return (
    <DocumentEditorContainerComponent
      id='container'
      height={'880px'}
      serviceUrl='https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web-services/api/documenteditor/'
      enableToolbar={true}
      // Set the page size to A4
      pageSettings={{
        size: 'A4',
      }}
      // Set the page orientation to landscape
      layoutType='Landscape'
    />
  );
}
export default App;
```

I tried to create a document editor using DocumentEditorContainerComponent in React syncfusion

what I need in it is I want to customize each page in that is there any solution for that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

We are glad to announce that our patch release (v22.1.36) has been rolled out successfully. In this ‎release, we have added the fix for the issue “Issue page size after inserting next page break”.‎

Please upgrade to the latest version packages to resolve this issue:‎

NPM link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@syncfusion/ej2-react-documenteditor

NuGet links:‎

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Ej2.Wordeditor.ASPNet.Core/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Ej2.Wordeditor.ASPNet.MVC5/

Feedback link:

https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/43825/issue-in-customize-the-page-size-after-inserting-next-page-break

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).